# Limit point s.t $ S\cap Q $ =$ \emptyset $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t $ S\cap \mathbb{Q} =\emptyset $. Which of following statements is true?

1. $S$ must have a limit point which belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$
2. $S$ must have a limit point  which belongs to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.
3. $S$ cannot be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$
4. $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ must have a limit point which belongs to $S$.

I tried this problem. I think $S$ is set of all irrational numbers. And since in every neighbourhood of rational number there are irrational numbers, therefor oprion 1 should be correct. But in book correct answer is option 4. Why isn't 1 true and how is 4 correct?

Comment: The intersection of rationals and irrationals is empty, so yes, this is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S$ is an infinite set of irrational numbers. It doesn't have to be the set of all irrationals.

To see why 1 is false consider $S=\{n+\sqrt2:n\in\Bbb Z\}$. This is an infinite set of irrational numbers which has no limit point, let alone one in $\Bbb Q$. In fact, this example shows that 2 and 3 are false also.

Option 4 is true because $\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus S$, and every real number is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: thank you for excellent answer