# Question about limit point.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S\cap \mathbb{Q}=\varnothing$. Then which of the following statement is true?

1. $S$ must have a limit point which belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. $S$ must have a limit point which belongs to $\mathbb{R/Q}$.
3. $S$ cannot be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.
4. $\mathbb{R}/S$ must have a limit point which belongs to $S$.

I consider the set {$\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt6,\sqrt7,\sqrt8,\sqrt10,..\sqrt15,\sqrt17,....$}

This set satisfies only option 4. So I thought answer should be 4, but answer key says option 3. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: By R/S, you mean $R\setminus S$, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119886/limit-point-s-t-s-cap-q-emptyset?rq=1

Comment: R not involving S

Comment: @Ben..my reasoning is correct then.

Comment: Option 4 is correct as the rationals are dense in the real numbers and $S\cap \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Only option 4. is true for every infinite set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}=\emptyset$ such that $S\cap\mathbb{Q}$.  Since $S$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus S$.  Since every irrational is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that every member of $S$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$.

You example shows that the other three options are, in general, false.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that for your example, $\Bbb{R} \setminus S$ has a limit point in $S$. But showing that it's true for one example isn't the same as showing that it *must* be true for *any* example.

Nonetheless, I think you're right. Every real number is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers, essentially by definition. So if you have some element of $S \subseteq \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, then every element of $S$ must be the limit of some sequence in $\Bbb{Q} \subseteq \Bbb{R} \setminus S$, and thus a limit point of $\Bbb{R}\setminus S$.

Your example of $S$ is indeed closed, as is $\{ \pi + n \mid n \in \Bbb{N} \}$, for example. So option 3 cannot be correct.